# Authorize attribe not working with mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, authorization, simplemembership

I have code written for MVC 4 using visual studio 2012... and i am trying to achieve role based authorization but it seem [Authorize] is not working for some reason.... and i still can get page through url even its controller action is initialize with [Authorize] attribute... second can i even try to look whole application by putting following code in global

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

my routing default set to login page as no unauthorized person can access to app

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and i trying to test by getting aa() view from directly url

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult aa()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Login code

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model._UserName, model._Password, persistCookie: false))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

        return View(model);
    }
```

and web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: i think i found the problem.... the web page was login even i cross the webpage... i believe i need to destroy cookie or section once user cross out webpage???

Comment: Have you checked after enabling Role Manager in web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

`InitializeSimpleMembership` needs to decorate your HomeController, NOT the AccountsController. As your HomeController/Index method is the entry point of your whole website, for `[Authorize`] to work, you need to have SimpleMembership initialized first, before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've created new MVC4 website and faced same problem: how to force authorization (and redirect to login page if not authorized).

I'm beginner in ASP.NET, and couldn't find simple answer (there is a lot about this, especially at stackoverflow but no one of these answers helped me). I've finally get it done after hours, so maybe I will help someone with this.

1. Add filter to global filters, which will require authorization everywhere (unless you'll set AllowAnonymous, but about it later). **Open App_Start/FilterConfig.cs** and:

   ```
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
       {
           filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
           // Add this line
           filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
       }
   ```
2. Now we need to set authorization in config file. **Open Web.config** in root dir of project and:

   ```
   <system.web>

       // start of modification

       // remove this line
       <authentication mode="None" />

       // add this lines
       <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" protection="All"></forms>
       </authentication>
       <authorization>
           <deny users="?" />
       </authorization>

       // end of modification

       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
   </system.web>
   ```

And thats all. Default login actions have [AllowAnonymous] tag by default so it just should work fine. It they not you need add them manually in Controllers/ like that:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

Hope helped someone.